# Elasticsearch - build scroll id manually

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a case in which I shouldn't make requests to get the scroll_id - I have to manage it somehow so I can get the URL for next pages offline (I am making GET requests against a certain site that exposes their Elasticsearch instance)

So basically, I have a certain URL containing Elasticsearch query and it returns me only 20 results out of 40(20 per request is the max size). I want to get an URL for the next pages - so given I had the connection to the Internet, I would just get the scroll_id from the first request and use it to make next ones.

But I want to avoid it and see if I can have a helper class that builds scroll ids by itself.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scroll_id` ties directly to some internal state (i.e. the context of the initial query) managed by ES and which eventually times out after the a given period of time.

Once the period times out, the search context is cleared and the scroll id is not valid anymore. I'm afraid there's no way you can craft a scroll id by hand.

But if the result set contains 40 results ans you can only retrieve 20 at a time, I suggest you simple set `from: 20` in your second query and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried that already - setting `from` doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Why not? Care to explain more?

Comment: `"reason": "Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [20] but was [40].`

Comment: Oh, they decreased the default window size from 10000 to 20. That's uncool!